# checkbox en swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

Necesito añadir unos `checkbox` con los dias de la semana como en esta imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esque no encuentro como hacerlo, he probado con la libreria `iCheckbox` pero no esta disponible.

**EDITADO**

La respuesta de [Error404](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16108/error404) está muy bien pero me haria falta que el `label` estuviera encima del `checkbox` no a la derecha

Comment: Hola @AlbertoMier, he visto tu nuevo edit. Creo que con la librería que adjunto en mi repuesta podrías poner la etiqueta encima del checkbox reescribiendo el método `drawButton` que se encuentra en el fichero `DLRadioButton.m`. Yo la verdad que no sé de Objective ni tengo un Mac ahora mismo para poder probarlo pero sobreescribiendo los valores en los que se calcula la derecha y haciéndolo para el top (los calculos cambiarán un poco), creo que podrías solucionar tu problema. Espero que esto te sirva.

Comment: Perfecto Gracias @Error404

Comment: Es un placer ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes echarle un vistazo a la librería [`DLRadioButton`](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton) en la que, tal y como la documentación indica, puedes crear los checkbox directamente desde el interface builder. Lo que hace realmente es crear la aparencia de un botón como si fuera un checkbox.

No es exactamente un tick lo que aparece en el checkbox pero igual te puede ser de ayuda. Estos son los ejemplos que ponen en la página de Github:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]